# Как рассчитать Content-Length для заголовка запроса POST на PHP CURL?

Tags: php, api, http, curl, soap

Для интеграции с сервисом Склад-Облако OptiCore нужно выполнить POST запрос ClientOrder_CreateUpdate в BODY которого содержится XML.
Обязательным заголовком HTTP для этого запроса является Content-Length, если он не указано то сервер просто рвет соединение по таймауту.

Подскажите как можно рассчитать это значение для Content-Length на PHP?

Вот тело запроса XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ClientOrder_CreateUpdate xmlns="http://cowms.ru/outbound"><User>Onwer54797</User><Pass>99dc684baa6af26767e849335db57488</Pass><ClientOrderCode>40</ClientOrderCode><OrderDate>2020-06-16</OrderDate><ExpectedDeliveryDate>2020-06-16</ExpectedDeliveryDate><ExpectedShipmentDate>2020-06-16</ExpectedShipmentDate><OutcomeWarehouse_id>48</OutcomeWarehouse_id><Owner_id>54797</Owner_id><Client_id>0</Client_id><Contractor_id>0</Contractor_id><Agent_id>0</Agent_id><DeliveryType_id>13</DeliveryType_id><DeliveryType_Parameters><DeliveryType_Parameters><ParameterName>PVZCode</ParameterName><ParameterValue>MSK2</ParameterValue></DeliveryType_Parameters><DeliveryType_Parameters><ParameterName>SUMTOPAY</ParameterName><ParameterValue>500.00</ParameterValue></DeliveryType_Parameters></DeliveryType_Parameters><DeliveryMode_id>1</DeliveryMode_id><ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_PositionCode>62</ClientOrder_PositionCode><Sku_id></Sku_id><Unit_id>784</Unit_id><StockType_id>0</StockType_id><Price>1199.00</Price><VAT>0</VAT><Qty>1</Qty><IncomeRequest_PositionCode></IncomeRequest_PositionCode><LabelText></LabelText></ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_PositionCode>63</ClientOrder_PositionCode><Sku_id></Sku_id><Unit_id>784</Unit_id><StockType_id>0</StockType_id><Price>779.00</Price><VAT>0</VAT><Qty>1</Qty><IncomeRequest_PositionCode></IncomeRequest_PositionCode><LabelText></LabelText></ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_Positions><ClientOrder_PositionCode>64</ClientOrder_PositionCode><Sku_id></Sku_id><Unit_id>784</Unit_id><StockType_id>0</StockType_id><Price>2999.00</Price><VAT>0</VAT><Qty>1</Qty><IncomeRequest_PositionCode></IncomeRequest_PositionCode><LabelText></LabelText></ClientOrder_Positions></ClientOrder_Positions></ClientOrder_CreateUpdate></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

В POSTMAN запросы проходят за счет того что это значение рассчитывается им автоматически, но как это сделать на PHP??? https://yadi.sk/i/oaSYQxLof1pS3w

Comment: Как обычно - curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-length:'.strlen($post_data)));

Comment: пробовал не прокатывает! Вообще что нужно высчитывать, длину строки тела BODY запроса? Длину строки XML? Если да то не прокатывает этот вариант... Тоже не понятно а почему?

Comment: Длина строки SOAP выше, [обрезанная](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485776/soap-content-length) от новых линий, и тип данных (Content-Length) по ссылке раз вы работаете с SOAP.

Comment: "Длина строки SOAP выше" - тот код что вы привели? curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-length:'.strlen($post_data))); а "обрезанная" как я понял нужно удалить первый и последный символы >< ?

Comment: Не нужно ничего удалять кроме новой линии (PHP_EOL)  в конце XML строки

Comment: $content_length = (intval(strlen(trim($content))));
Вот так я его рассчитываю теперь и для проверке указываю принудительно в POSTMAN и запрос проходит, я получаю ответ, т.е значение рассчитывается правильно! Но при отправки аналогичного запроса из скрипта PHP ответа не получаю... Вместо этого получаю ошибку "Recv failure: Connection reset by peer"  Что же ото может быть?

Comment: А это, батенька, уже [другой вопрос!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10285700/curl-error-recv-failure-connection-reset-by-peer-php-curl)

Comment: Выяснив что из PostMan запросы проходят корректно, решил посмотреть все исходящие запросы из него через Fiddler в итоге выяснил что из него Content-Length: 578 а в моем скрипте рассчитывается как 564 (вот так $content_length = (intval(strlen(trim($content)))) ) разницу преплюсовал $content_length = (intval(strlen(trim($content))))+ 14; и запросы пошли... Но блин, что это за ерунда! Почему же этот Content-Length рассчитывается по разному, как прийти к консенсусу?

Comment: Как же все таки расcчитать этот Content-Length!? strlen его считает не правильно! Потому что в PostMan отправка аналогичного тела запроса с XML идет с большим значением в Content-Length! Это какой то порочный круг, не ужели нет метода в PHP для корректного расчета, я в шоке...

Comment: Возьмите XML, отправьте его и посмотрите через [Inspector](https://blog.postman.com/debugging-postman-requests/) значение длины. На основе этого (и самого запроса) можно будет понять что именно используется для вычисления.

Comment: Выяснили причину не правильного расчета! Это Битрикс и его php_value mbstring.func_overload 2 для установки в UTF-8 !!! С таким параметром strlen заменяется mb_strlen() которая считает кол-во символов а не байт... Сабж можно закрыть, решено, все смпасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный и безопасный способ, в том числе при перегрузке функции `mbstring.func_overload`:

```
$content_length = mb_strlen($content, '8bit');
```

Ответ на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9718273/9435985)

Answer (score 0):

Это Битрикс... и при mbstring.func_overload 2 strlen которая считает в байтах, замещается mb_strlen считающая кол-во символов а не байт, из-за этого и не правильный расчет.

Comment: Старайтесь давать более разврнутые ответы

Answer (score 0):

Вот решение

```
$content_length = file_put_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/upload/tmp/tmp.xml", $content);
```

подсказали тут
https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/support/forum/messages/forum6/topic133333/message658007/?result=vote4user#message658007

Comment: Зачем мусорить диск? `file_put_contents("/dev/null", $content);` тогда уж.

Comment: что тогда уж не понял?

Comment: `file_put_contents` создает файл, значит это работа с медленным диском, плюс расходуется место, плюс файл может быть открыт для записи еще одним процессом. А `/dev/null` - это устройство не имеет этих трех недостатков.